# How can I calculate percentages of match between 2 Javascript objects?

Tags: javascript

I have a need to calculate percentages of match between 2 Javascript objects. How can I achieve this?

Examples:

```
obj1={key1: "val1", key2: "val2", key3: "val3", key4: "val4"}
obj2={key5: "val5", key6: "val6"}
//result should be: 0%


obj1={key1: "val1", key2: "val2", key3: "val3", key4: "val4"}
obj2={key1: "val1", key2: "val2"}
//result should be: 50%
```

Comment: % of matched keys or values?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did it go wrong? People are willing to help, not do it for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not specified exactly how you want such a percentage calculated. There are at least four different ways of measuring percent similarity between two objects:

- the percent of the keys in the 1st object that can be found in the 2nd,
- the percent of the values in the 1st object that can be found in the 2nd, including duplicates,
- the percent of the values in the 1st object that can be found in the 2nd, with no duplicates allowed, and
- the percent of {key:value} pairs in the 1st object that can be found in the 2nd object.

Note that order of the two objects matters, i.e. calling with (obj1,obj2) may produce different results than calling with (obj2,obj1).

The second option above counts each instance of repeated values in the 2nd object, making it possible to return values higher than 100%, e.g. comparing {a:42} and {x:42, y:42} returns 200%. This might not initially seem reasonable but is mathematically valid based on how the calculation is defined. Such duplicates are not allowed in the third option, such that comparing {a:42} and {x:42, y:42} returns 100%. In either case, duplicate values in the first object are not counted, e.g. comparing {a:42, b:42} and {x:42} yields 50% in both cases. Such duplicates are not a relevant consideration for the first and fourth options above as JavaScript objects cannot have repeated keys.

The code snippet below demonstrates all four methods.

```js
const obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 3};
const obj2 = {a: 1, b: 1, e: 2, f: 2, g: 3, h: 5};

const keys = obj => Object.keys(obj);
const toPct = a => 100 / keys(a).length;

const pctSameKeys = (a, b) =>
  keys(b).reduce((num,key) =>
    keys(a).indexOf(key) > -1 ? num + 1 : num, 0) * toPct(a);

const pctSameValuesIncludingDuplicates = (a, b) =>
  keys(b).map(key => b[key]).reduce((num,v) =>
    keys(a).map(key => a[key]).indexOf(v) > -1 ? num + 1 : num, 0) * toPct(a);

const pctSameValuesNoDuplicates = (a, b) =>
  Array.from(new Set(keys(b).map(key => b[key]))).reduce((num,v) =>
    keys(a).map(key => a[key]).indexOf(v) > -1 ? num + 1 : num, 0) * toPct(a);

const pctSameProps = (a, b) =>
  keys(b).reduce((num,key) =>
    a[key] === b[key] ? num + 1 : num, 0) * toPct(a);

console.log('obj1:', JSON.stringify(obj1));
console.log('obj2:', JSON.stringify(obj2));
console.log('% same keys:                   ', pctSameKeys(obj1, obj2));
console.log('% same values, incl duplicates:', pctSameValuesIncludingDuplicates(obj1, obj2));
console.log('% same values, no duplicates:  ', pctSameValuesNoDuplicates(obj1, obj2));
console.log('% same properties (k/v pairs): ', pctSameProps     (obj1, obj2));
```

The following code snippet shows essentially exactly the same thing, but is written in an even more functional style (but see [this answer on the Computer Engineering site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/342038/232250) to see how my code here can potentially be re-written in a still functional but more readable style):

```js
const obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 3};
const obj2 = {a: 1, b: 1, e: 2, f: 2, g: 3, h: 5};

// x or X is key or value or key/value pair

const getXs = (obj, getX) =>
  Object.keys(obj).map(key => getX(obj, key));

const getPctSameXs = (getX, filter) =>
  (objA, objB) =>
    (filter ? filter(getXs(objB, getX)) : getXs(objB, getX)).reduce(
      (numSame, x) =>
        getXs(objA, getX).indexOf(x) > -1 ? numSame + 1 : numSame,
      0
    ) / Object.keys(objA).length * 100;

const pctSameKeys       = getPctSameXs((obj, key) => key);
const pctSameValsDups   = getPctSameXs((obj, key) => obj[key]);
const pctSameValsNoDups = getPctSameXs((obj, key) => obj[key], vals => [...new Set(vals)]);
const pctSameProps      = getPctSameXs((obj, key) => JSON.stringify( {[key]: obj[key]} ));

console.log('obj1:', JSON.stringify(obj1));
console.log('obj2:', JSON.stringify(obj2));
console.log('% same keys:                   ', pctSameKeys      (obj1, obj2));
console.log('% same values, incl duplicates:', pctSameValsDups  (obj1, obj2));
console.log('% same values, no duplicates:  ', pctSameValsNoDups(obj1, obj2));
console.log('% same properties (k/v pairs): ', pctSameProps     (obj1, obj2));
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not completely clear from your limited number of examples exactly how it should behave, but I believe your requirement can be re-worded:

> What percentage of items in `obj1` exist and are equal in `obj2`?

For this, you can simply count:

```
var count = [0,0];
for( var key in obj1) {
    count[1]++; // total count
    if( obj2.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj2[key] === obj1[key]) {
        count[0]++; // match count
    }
}
var percentage = count[0]/count[1]*100+"%";
```

Of course, if your specification is different, then this won't be quite right, but it should at least get you going in the right direction.

Comment: You have to check for the keys that are exclusivelly in `obj2` as well!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is light on details. So I will assume you want to look up values in 1 Array object and see if they occur in the 2nd Array.

You have two options.

1.) Use `SQL` - Convert both of them into tables and then do join on their Values. Inner join should only return things that are common between them thus giving you a count.

2.) Use a `HashMap` - Convert the big Array into a Hash Map. Iterate through the small array and see if the values in the small array exist in the HashMap. If they do then you can keep a running count.

3.) Regular `Array` Search - Just like going through the Array normally you can see if there are matches.

Comment: where are you seeing an array?

Comment: SQL seems quite overkill o_O

Comment: I don't but it can be converted into one.

Comment: You say "1 Array Object". This is javascript, not certain what language you think this is but it's not an array object. They are both objects and all he needs to do is iterate over the objects and keep a running count of matches.